# Filtering Base Django User by multiple groups

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I'm using base Django User and Group models. My goal is to get User queryset containing all User object who are assigned to multiple groups at the same time.
For example I two groups and three users:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

a = Group.objects.create(name='a')
b = Group.objects.create(name='b')

user_a = User.objects.create_user('a', 'a@a.com', 'a')
user_a.groups.add(a)
user_b = User.objects.create_user('b', 'b@b.com', 'b')
user_b.groups.add(b)
user_ab = User.objects.create_user('ab', 'ab@ab.com', 'ab')
user_ab.groups.add(a)
user_ab.groups.add(b)
```

I have tried filtering using __in on groups nad Q, but with no effect

```
from django.db.models import Q

User.objects.filter(groups__in=[a,b]).distinct()
<QuerySet [<User: a>, <User: ab>, <User: b>]>
User.objects.filter(Q(groups=a) & Q(groups=b))
<QuerySet []>
```

My expected result would be:

```
User.objects.filter(???)
<QuerySet [<User: ab>]>
```

Comment: `User.objects.filter(groups=a).filter(groups=b)`

Comment: Oh my, I don't know why i did not tried that one. Worked like charm, thank you :) You want to post it as answer so I can accept it or nah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement two `JOIN`s by using two [**`.filter(…)`** clauses <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter), and thus filter with:

```
User.objects.filter(groups=a).filter(groups=b)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why User.objects.filter(Q(groups=a) & Q(groups=b)) is not working the same way?

Comment: @TrueGopnik: because when you use `Q(groups=a) & Q(groups=b)` you basically say it should have a group that is both `a` and `b` at the same time.